# Parallel downloads with Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

How can I download data from multiple sources in parallel and present a complete result?
I already have a program looping through a set of classes and invoking a getter/loader method, but there must be a better/elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Be more descriptive in you're question please!

Answer (score 0):

Java is **a multithreaded programming language** which means we can develop multithreaded program using Java. A multithreaded program contains two or more parts that can run concurrently and each part can handle different task at the same time making optimal use of the available resources specially when your computer has multiple CPUs.

By definition multitasking is when multiple processes share common processing resources such as a CPU. Multithreading extends the idea of multitasking into applications where you can subdivide specific operations within a single application into individual threads. Each of the threads can run in parallel. The OS divides processing time not only among different applications, but also among each thread within an application.

Multithreading enables you to write in a way where multiple activities can proceed concurrently in the same program.

```
    class RunnableDemo implements Runnable {

   private Thread t;

   private String threadName;

   RunnableDemo( String name){

       threadName = name;

       System.out.println("Creating " +  threadName );
   }

   public void run() {

      System.out.println("Running " +  threadName );

      try {

         for(int i = 4; i  0; i--) {

            System.out.println("Thread: " + threadName + ", " + i);

            // Let the thread sleep for a while.

            Thread.sleep(50);

         }
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {

         System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " interrupted.");

     }

     System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");

   }

   public void start ()

   {

      System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );

      if (t == null)

      {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);

         t.start ();

      }
   }

>}

  public class TestThread {


       public static void main(String args[]) {

          RunnableDemo R1 = new RunnableDemo( "Thread-1");

      R1.start();

      RunnableDemo R2 = new RunnableDemo( "Thread-2");

      R2.start();

   }   

}
```